# PHP Loop Array Update Values From Another Array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, bigcommerce

I have an array created from a .CSV

```
function readCSV($csvFile){
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}

// Set path to CSV file
$csvFile = 'lmco_inventory.csv';
$csv = readCSV($csvFile);
```

The first column is SKU and the second column is Inventory_Level. I want to loop through another array and update the Inventory_Level based on the Inventory_Level from the .CSV array. The unique value between the two array's is the SKU field.

Here is my other array:

```
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 9 ; $i++){
    $filter = array('page' => $i, 'limit' => 250);
    $products = Bigcommerce::getProducts($filter);
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        echo "$product->id\n";
    }
}
```

Instead of echo "$product->id\n"; I want to align both arrays to where SKU = SKU and then update Inventory_Level from the .CSV to the $products array.

Hope that makes sense.

**EDIT**

```
Sample .CSV data

SKU | Inventory
1     5
2     1
3     7
4     21
5     500

In plain english this is what I want: 
foreach ($products as $product) { 
//find where $product->sku = $csv->sku 
//then $product->inventory_level gets the value of $csv->inventory_value 
//loop through all objects in $product array until complete 
//done
```

Comment: Mind supplying a piece of sample data and the expected output? :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the arrays are structured correctly, you could do the following. Notice the `&` in the foreach declaration, this makes sure that `$product` is a reference to the actual value in the `$products` array instead of a copy.

```
foreach ($products as &$product) {
    foreach ($csv as $row) {
        if ($product->sku == $row['sku']) {
            $product->inventory_level = $csv['inventory_value'];
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that I haven't used BigCommerce so I am unsure of the structure of its returned data, but this should give you a general idea.